# Connectedness: with respect to a larger metric space, or with respect to itself only?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I asked a similar question on the forum earlier, and felt as if I had the issue clarified, but having come upon the problem again in other situations, it is clear that I'm still confused.

Consider the set $X \subset \mathbb{R} = [a,b] \setminus \{c\}$ for some $c$ such that $a < c < b.$ The textbook says $X$ is disconnected and qualifies its statement by putting forth the "separation" $X = [a,c) \sqcup (c,b].$ With respect to the metric subspace $X$, the two intervals $[a,c),(c,b]$ are clopen. However, they are not with respect to $\mathbb{R}.$ Do you have to qualify "connectedness" with a "respect to," as in, $X$ is connected with respect to $\mathbb{R},$ but disconnected with respect to itself. Can you comment on the connectedness of the natural numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Connectedness* is a notion about a topological space, not a relative  notion. When one speaks of a connected subset $X$ of a topological space $E$, it means the topological space $X$, endowed with the `induced topology`, is connected.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The natural numbers is a disconnected set, right? For $\{1\} \cup \{2\} \cdots = \mathbb{N},$ and each singleton is a clopen proper subset of $\mathbb{N}?$ S And any subset ("subspace") of the natural numbers is also disconnected.

Comment: Yes, absolutrly. They're even *totally disconnected* spaces.